# LXC running php application

Tags: php, apache, virtual-machine, ubuntu-server, lxc

I have this code in file called index.html in directory `/var/www/html/index.html`.

```
<html> 
<body>
<?php
   echo phpinfo();
?>
</html>
</body>
```

But when I try to see what it prints on the browser it doesn't show anything at all, or sometimes it downloads a file.
[This is what browser prints (Nothing).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpdhP.png)

If I try to look [the source code and it seems like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ws1tu.png)
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I searched a lot and tried a few things, but nothing really seemed to work.

I'd really appreciate if someone could list me some things to look up or where's the solution to this problem. I think it'll be very simple but I have no idea of what to do now.

**edit:** output of `php --version`[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RYwh.png).

Comment: Don't echo it. Just call it. `echo "<?php phpinfo(); ?>" > index.html` The return value, [according to the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php), is a boolean. The call itself should print the desired info.

Comment: Welp. I tried and it didn't work. The output was just `echo ""` I tried to do it on a .php file. But it keep downloading it.

Comment: Oops... Been a long day. Obviously it's not going to eval the php with an html extension. If you rename it to `.php` it downloads the file? Then it seems like apache is not properly configured with a PHP interpreter.

Comment: Yeah! I've modified the `/etc/apache/apache2.conf' with weird lines, but it didn't work either.

Comment: Do you have access to the command line of this host? Can you try running `php --version` and send the output? (verify php actually is installed)

Comment: I didn't figure it out how to embed an image, so edited the post. It seems to be installed.

Comment: Cool, so that shows you are using php7, have you enabled the Apache module? `sudo a2enmod php7.0`

Comment: If it's not installed, install it, `apt-get install libapache2-mod-php` then enable it, then restart Apache.

Comment: A did it both, and it output `Considering conflict php5 for php7.0:
Module php7.0 already enabled`. What's next?

Comment: Uninstall php5 is you plan to use php7? Hmm, php7 already enabled... I am not sure..